# How do I find the newly appended key value of a php array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have a class that stores info about a photo. It has a bunch of public "getters" and "setters" to keep me honest. When a comment about a photo is added publicly like this:

```
$photo->addComment('Blue');
```

the class will call another function that will add the comment to a private array of comments like this:

```
$comments[] = array('comment'=>$new_comment,'time'=>$new_time,'user'=>$new_user);
```

What is the best method for determining the new `$key` that was just created so that `echo $comments[$key]['comment'];` will print 'Blue'?

Comment: You could make your `addComment()` method return that last inserted index.

Comment: `$comment = end($comments); echo $comment['comment'];`

Comment: @NullUserException This is more like what I am looking for.  Would a call to `key(end($comments))` suffice? Even if another comment was added at the same time.

Comment: @buster: nope. `key` as well as `end` accepts reference to an array.

Comment: @zerkms right, so `end($comments); $new_key=key($comments);`

Comment: @buster: as it is in my answer ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
end($comments);
$key = key($comments);
```

Comment: I can't say I'm a huge fan of messing with the array's internal pointer.

Comment: @NullUserException♦: me either, but it's a trivial solution. No reason to overcomplicate while this one fits the requirements.

Comment: Is it possible that two users could post at the same time, before the new `$key` is committed to a file or sql?

Comment: @buster: yep. `$key` may be the same for 2 users. Use autoincrement column or sequence in DB for addressing to a comments in an unique manner.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$key = sizeof($comments) - 1
```

Comment: `$comments = array('a' => 1);
$comments[] = 'q';

var_dump($comments);` it won't work in **all** cases, but only if the array is number indexed without gaps

Comment: `$comments[] = ...` suggests this is the case.

Comment: @Salman A: look at my example. I also used `$comments[]` - so it doesn't guarantee anything

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `end` function (http://php.net/manual/en/function.end.php).

If your goal is print out 'Blue', this is your most direct solution:

`echo end($comments)['comment']`

Note: this example uses array dereferencing introduced in PHP 5.4 (http://www.php.net/archive/2011.php#id2011-06-28-1).

Comment: It would worth to add php version requirements.

Comment: @Elliot B.: "uses the same syntax" --- where?

Comment: @Elliot B.: in the original post it's the generic array access syntax, that works since php 3. Your code uses array dereferencing introduced in php 5.4. `$comments[$key]['comment']` is not equal to `end($comments)['comment']`

Answer (score 0):

for a more accurate method something like this might work:

```
$keys = array_keys($comments); // get just the keys
$reverse = array_reverse($keys); // reverse order
$lastKey = $keys[0]; // get what is now the first key
```

will allow for gaps in indexing

Comment: Why to perform reverse if you could just `$lastKey = end($keys);`